# Customise output of $content in Drupal nodes

Tags: drupal, customization

I have a custom content type called 'business-profile' and I have the template files 'node-business_profile.tpl.php' which works fine, but I want to be able to edit the layout of the $content variable

ie I want display some elements in particular divs etc

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is drupal 6, use the devel and theamer modules to show you the templates and how they can be overridden.

In short most of the variables in content can be overridden with custom field templates.